# Implementation of google mail gadget for openerp

Tags: odoo, google-gadget

I have been using thunderbird plugin for openerp.

Since I am using google mail I was wondering if there is any implementation to do so using a gmail gadget or google contextual gadget.

I tried looking, but couldn't find any.

Any pointers / suggestions. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is nice feature indeed but with Google Gadgets API we have problem that we can not do a XML-RPC called clearly and their no mature API that is supported by Google Gadget APIs, so for now their is no Google Gadget API available for OE. But we we have XML-RPC request facility available, you can go for it cause development for the same is so easy.
Project was started by  OF but it was dropped due to API limitation.

Regards.